# Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-authentication

I was trying to implement the Google auth feature and it works well from my page but within my Iframe it's been blocked, can someone please help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lBxq.png)

Comment: Please share relevant codes as well...

Comment: Thank you @Aditya for your reply, I had followed this documentation for the configs https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2. This is my config file:

`module App
  # Main application class
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.exceptions_app = routes

    config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ENV['APP_URL'],
      'Access-Control-Request-Method' => %w[GET POST OPTIONS].join(','),
      'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
    })`